# remove node based on child node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Currently I have my XSL working to remove nodes with certain attributes (thanks stackoverflow).  Given the follwing xml

```
<Document>
  <Node1>
   <Node2>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 etv:severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
 </Node1>
</Document>
```

with this xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:etv="urn:com.etv/etv"
    xmlns:iso="urn:iso">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/iso:Document/iso:Node1/iso:Node2/iso:Node3[(@etv:severity='skip')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Noticing the 3rd instance of Node2 has all Node3's in error.  Id like to also remove all Node 2 in that case.  can this be done in 1 transformation?

per allens question below, the current output is as follows

```
<Document>
  <Node1>
   <Node2>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 etv:severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2>
  </Node2>
 </Node1>
</Document>
```

Comment: could you add your output please for your input? Thank you

Comment: updated above Allen.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an input XML with the proper namespaces declared, you can add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="iso:Node2[not(*/@etv:severity!='skip')]"/>
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsX.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a ton.  sorry for improper namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have this simplified input file (you have too many namespaces do you really need them? If necessary then I will let you fix the stylesheet accordingly)

**INPUT:**

```
$ more document.xml 
<Document>
  <Node1>
   <Node2>
    <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
    <Node3 severity="skip"> stuff </Node3>
  </Node2>
 </Node1>
</Document>
```

**STYLESHEET:**

```
$ more document.xslt 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:etv="urn:com.etv/etv" xmlns:iso="urn:iso" exclude-result-prefixes="etv iso">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Node2">
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(./Node3[@severity='ok']) = 0">
                         <Node2></Node2><!-- you can remove this line if you do not want to have Node2 produced-->
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Node2><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></Node2>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Node3[@severity='skip']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**RESULT:**

```
$ java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:document.xml -xsl:document.xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
   <Node1>
      <Node2>
         <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
         <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
      </Node2>
      <Node2>
         <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
         <Node3 severity="ok"> stuff </Node3>
      </Node2>
      <Node2/>
   </Node1>
</Document>
```

You can completely remove empty `Node2` by commenting the line in the `when` in the stylesheet. Good luck